# End the video when the overlay video is finished

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have an overlayed video which can be longer or shorter than the background video.

**Case 1:** If the background video is longer, the video should end when the overlayed video is over.

**Case 2:** If the background video is shorter, it should repeat the last frame of the video until the overlayed video is over.

With the `shortest=1` and `eof_action` commands I haven't been able to achieve this without compromising one of the above cases.  For example with `shortest=1` in the overlay command, case #1 works but in case #2, both videos freeze when the background video ends while the audio plays out.

Note that only the overlayed video has audio.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the following filter to the bg video: `tpad=stop=-1:stop_mode=clone` and use `eof_action=endall` in overlay.